# Json encoding and decoding

Tags: c#, json, encoding, decoding

I am using HTTP Post in an application that I am writing. I am passing rich text field value in that post. I've tried url and html encoding/decoding to pass this html text but I the results that are showing up after decoding are not maintaining the formatting and styles. I have tried various suggestions but I am getting nowhere. What is the best way to encode decode and any code samples are definitely appreciated.

Thanks

**I am posting the data below.**

"The increasingly bitter and public shareholder dispute at Cato between Ed Crane and the Koch brothers has brought to light Ed Crane’s collaboration with the Democrat Media Complex, as well as troubling accounts of some of his past dealings with his Board. \n\nIn the Crane Chronicles Part I, we reported that Ed Crane partnered with left-wing New Yorker writer Jane Mayer to launch a smear campaign against the Koch brothers. Crane then used Mayer’s hit piece as justification for arguing that Cato should distance itself from the Kochs.  \n\nIn the Crane Chronicles Part II, we reported on Crane’s antics at a Cato Board dinner at which he shouted at two of his board members before storming out of the room, leaving Cato donors, policy analysts, and senior managers in stunned silence. \n\nIn response to the Cato shareholder dispute, a number of industry insiders have described in unflattering terms the culture at Cato under Ed Crane’s leadership.  \n\nSteven Hayward of National Review recently stated, “I can also see
 how Crane can make Steve Jobs look warm and cuddly by comparison (I suspect Ed will regard this as a compliment).” \n\nErick Erickson of Red State described Crane’s actions throughout the controversy over Cato’s shareholder agreement more brusquely, calling Crane’s behavior “egregious” and “frankly rather spoiled.” Erickson concludes, “If Cato is to die, it will be because of Ed Crane’s leadership.” \n\nWhile offering praise to Ed Crane, Forbes writer John Tamny concedes that, “Cato’s impish, irascible and very strident culture is a function of the man who runs it….the atmosphere at Cato events is probably quite unlike what one would witness at other think tank gatherings.” \n\nIn the latest development, perhaps emboldened by the raging shareholder dispute, former staffers of this gold-standard of libertarian think tanks have actively come forward to paint a disturbing picture of the work environment at Cato under Ed Crane’s leadership – suggesting that it is, at least according to them, hostile and degrading
 to women. \n\n“It’s hardly the climate you would want your daughter working or interning in,” said one former Cato employee in an interview with Breitbart News. “Most of the scholars at Cato are fine, decent, and sincere people. But Ed Crane’s dismissive and degrading attitude toward women can make them feel more like meat than equals.” \n\n“I think it’s pretty open knowledge inside of Cato that most attractive female professional staff members have been the target of unsolicited sexual advances by Ed Crane,” another former Cato employee told Breitbart News. Asked why such behavior was tolerated, the one-time Cato employee replied: “In a place with no formal system of redress there becomes a complacent attitude of ‘Oh, that’s just Ed.’ Or ‘He’s probably had too much to drink.’” \n\nContacted by email for comment, Director of Media Relations Chris Kennedy responded, \"If anyone wants to cite any actual legal complaints ever made against Ed or other members of Cato's management, we'd respond to them. But we're 
not going to respond to baseless rumor and innuendo leveled by unnamed sources.\" \n\nCertainly, these are stunning allegations (and similar allegations go way back). Cato is of such critical importance to the libertarian movement, that it is incumbent on its Board to full vet them. If accurate, they raise serious questions about how and why the behavior of Cato’s chief leader would be tolerated for so long by so many. \n\nPart of the explanation, says one former Cato employee, is that, unlike other think tanks, “Cato has no real endowment”; its sizable operating budget is largely contingent on Crane’s ability to raise millions of dollars annually. \n\n“Everyone’s paychecks hinge on Ed Crane’s ability to bring in the dollars,” explained on former Cato employee. “That means people tolerate behavior from Ed that Ed would never tolerate in others.” \n\nThe sense one gets from speaking to those closest to Cato’s culture is one of a leader with an authoritarian hold on power. As one former Cato staff member explain
ed, “The gallows humor among Cato-ites holds that what Cato really stands for is this: ‘Crane And The Others.’” \n\n***Note: In addition to and apart from these accusations about Ed Crane’s behavior, a recent blog post by Robert Wenzel of the Economic Policy Journal made mention of allegations of serious misconduct by a “top Cato official.” Lew Rockwell also commented on the allegations. Breitbart News cannot currently verify the accuracy of Mr. Wenzel’s allegations, or the identity of the “top Cato official” to which he refers."

Comment: You don't need url or html encoding to send your values using POST

Comment: What do you use json for? If the textarea is simply inside a `<form>` being submitted, the browser does the encoding for you. Or are you using ajax requests?

Comment: I am using json to pass my values over from one server to another. It's a form with different text fields and one of them is a rich text field.

The problem with rich text is that c the double quotes in there are causing the json property to be truncated or returning an error from c sharp.

Comment: I posted the data above. As you can see all the html formatting is gone - no paragraphs, no line breaks, nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.NET is the best library out there to work with JSON. I used encoding and decoding functions from there and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

You could use base64 encoding and decoding.